# A Request scoped bean inside a Request scoped bean

Tags: java, spring

Have 2 classes configured which look similar to :

```
class ParentImpl implements Parent {

private Child child;

@Autowired
public void setChild(Child child) {
this.child = child
}


public void accessChild() {
// Access the child here
}
  
}


class ChildImpl implements Child {

}
```

Both of them have been configured to request scope Spring bean. Similar code snippet below:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public Parent initParent() {
  return new ParentImpl()

}

@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public Child initChild() {
  return new ChildImpl();

}
}
```

They both were work absolutely fine. However, at a certain timestamp **t** , **child** inside the **parent** object comes null and the method **accessChild** throws a *NullPointerException*

Would like to know under what circumstances this can happen ?

**Note:**

1. Have added logs in the method **initChild** and spring doesn't call the method. However the initParent is still getting called.
2. Program continue to work for some days, so it's not 100% reproducible thing. If we restart the server when this issue occurs, everything works as expected.

Comment: If the bean dependency is _required_ (it will throw an NPE if not present), then use constructor injection instead of setter injection, which is for optional dependencies (such as a `Clock` that is normally the system clock but can be replaced for testing).

Comment: For the above code, under what circumstances do you think it can happen ?